# Roll back deployment stategy and performance testing (2010)

Tags: 2010, deployment, backup, restore

I am currently on the cusp of deploying a solution which will be upgrading existing .wsp solutions and also running a powershell script to upgrade masterpages, content types and page layouts on the farm.

The wsp solutions deploy new and updated content types, fields, web parts etc which also include updated dll's.
Ive been asked to demonstrate 2 things:

1. Performance test the difference of before and after the deployment.
2. Privide a rollback mechanism should the deployment go sour.

I have no idea how to go about doing either of these tasks. Does anyone know of or use any methods to test performance? They are talking about page loads etc. Also what are the roll back options, other than a farm backup and restore.
My powershell script is modifying more than 2000 mysites and around 300 other site collections. Rollback? Anyone have any experience of an easier solution?
The backup and restore solution will also take a long time considering the size of the data in the farm.

Comment: A backup and restore might take a long time, but the cost of that time might be cheaper than the development cost of adding in rollback capability to the solution deployment. Unless you're talking hundreds of GB of data, a backup & restore shouldn't take more than a few hours. Basically you're talking hours to backup/restore versus days to add in rollback.

Comment: Also - the time taken to restore a backup should already be a known variable in a good DR plan.